# What could be the Regular Expression for the following

Tags: regex, unix

```
$ cat t1.txt:
ABCD_EFG_HIJK
ABCD_HJIJ_IJKL
```

---

What could be the Regex for the above two lines .
Even for one of the lines

Or

Scenario is 4characters followedby underscore followed by characters ( any number) followed by underscore followed by characters (any number) again underscore characters .. ends with characters.

`4characters_(minimum of 1 characters)_(minimum of1 characters)_(ends with minimum of 1 characters)`.

Note : It starts with 4 characters.

Comment: You talk about "ends with characters", but any non-empty string trivially ends with a character. If you meant "letter" there, you should write that, and edit your question to revisit your other usages of "character" too. Your use of "underscore character" indicates that this does not apply to all uses of "character".

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

After edit, the question is to find a regex that matches a string that starts with 4 chars, followed by minimum of 1 group which consists of '_' followed by minimal 1 character.

```
[A-Z]{4}(_[A-Z]+)+
```

explanation:

```
[A-Z]{4}             # exactly 4 picks from A-Z
(                    # group 1 start
 _[A-Z]+             # "_" followed by 1 or more character out of A-Z
)+                   # group 1 end. Repeat group 1 1 or more times.
```

You can play with it at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/92ZAwO/3)

In the above regex I've chosen for capitals as characters, since this is suggested by the question. However, this could be a set of letters e.g., which would change the regex to:

```
[a-zA-Z]{4}(_[a-zA-Z]+)+
```

Comment: Any number is not a valid scenario, minimum 1character should be there . So I am editing the question.

Comment: Changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: Hi Just one thing more if if add some more text before the text.
like if it is

abcd#hjkl_yui_podv.lpokmnv

Now if I want to extract hjkl_yui_podv.lpokmnv from this how would we do it

Comment: You would have to add a '.' to the character class in group1, so this becomes `[a-zA-Z]{4}(?:_[.a-zA-Z]+)+`. Check this at https://regex101.com/r/ETkTsd/2.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by `any number of character` at least one character, this is the most correct answer: `/^[A-Za-z0-9]{4}_([A-Za-z0-9]+_)+[A-Za-z0-9]+$/g`.

If you want, you can try this solution at regex website: [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/)

**EDIT:** If you want to have only capital letters, than you should remove `a-z` and `0-9` from square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
[^_\n]+_[^_]+_[^_\n]+
```

Match everything except new line `\n` and `_`
between underscores

Comment: *"It starts with 4 characters"* How does your regex meet this condition?